# SQLAlchemy can't connect to a local database using an absolute path

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

After much hassle with getting the POSTGRESQL program configured with a user with a capital letter and figuring out how to write out an abs path in windows:
`set DATABASE_URL=postgresql:///c:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\data\\books.db`

(no spaces ! I learned this the hardway !)

in Windows I am still having difficulty connecting to the local databse I created with a test script I have.

within PSQL there exists a database called 'books' which shows up with '\z'.  The default directory for saving databases has not been changed from POSTGRESQL default. and yet when I run the program :

```
import csv
import os

from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


def import_csv():
    f = open("books.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for isbn, title, author, year in reader:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author, year) VALUES (:isbn, :title, :author, :year)",
                    {"isbn":isbn, "title":title, "author":author, "year":year})
    db.commit()

import_csv()
```

Why does this not connect ? ( I have cut out a lot of extraneous code here to show the active parts I am dealing with)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After much hassle with getting the POSTGRESQL program configured with a user with a capital letter and figuring out how to write out an abs path in windows: set DATABASE_URL=postgresql:///c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data\books.db

Postgres is a database server. You can't connect directly to one of the underlying files like that. You need to connect to the network service provided by the Postgres database server.

The acceptable SQLAlchemy URLs for connecting to a Postgres database are shown [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#postgresql).

Comment: I changed the code to reflect the format you linked to: `engine = create_engine('postgresql://Robert:password@localhost/books')` where user and password are the correct values   and I get the same error.  I also tried connecting as user 'postgres' but I get the same error.  idk what's going on

Comment: The postgresql installation is in a different directory than the python file I am working with.  Also, something that came up that might be pertinent:  I am able to see the database within psql from the CLI :  `psql -U postgres -h localhost` but am unable to seemingly connect to postgres doing `psql -U Robert -h localhost` , even though user 'Robert' comes up in the list of roles using the command `\z` within postgres.

Comment: If you can't connect with `psql` using the name `Robert` and the your password, that suggests you haven't correctly configured things on the Postgres side.  Try your Python code using the `postgres` user and see if you can connect.

Comment: OK.  I feel like a dufus.  Apparently I had created a table but not a database.  I went into psql and did a `CREATE TABLE books;` and then tried again with the correct set DATABASE_URL (user postgres) and apparently the program is running, although now I am fighting another syntax issue... progress at last!  thanks dude